# How do I secure my other React pages/routes with KeyCloak?

Tags: reactjs, keycloak

I need to secure my React pages with KeyCloak. Most beginner tutorials only include one page samples (I know that React is ideally for single-page applications but it's needed for the frontend) on authentication with KeyCloak. Below are my codes:

(App.js)

```
// imports

export default function App () {
    return (
      <Router>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' component={Public}></Route>
            <Route exact path='/dashboard' component={Secured}></Route>
            <Route exact path='/settings' component={Settings}></Route>
          </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
}
```

(Public.js)

```
// imports

class Public extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
        <div className="container">
          <ul>
            <li><Link to="/">Public component</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="/dashboard">Login</Link></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Public;
```

(Secured.js)

```
// imports

const styles = theme => ({
    appBarSpacer: theme.mixins.toolbar,
    content: {
        flexGrow: 1,
        height: '100vh',
        overflow: 'auto',
    }
});

class Secured extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { keycloak: null, authenticated: false };
        this.state = { page: 'home' }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const keycloak = Keycloak('/keycloak.json');
        keycloak.init({ onLoad: 'login-required' }).then(authenticated => {
            this.setState({ keycloak: keycloak, authenticated: authenticated });
        });
    }

    render() {
        const { classes } = this.props;
        if (this.state.keycloak) {
            if (this.state.authenticated) {
                return (
                    <div>
                        <Dashboard keycloak={this.state.keycloak} />
                    </div>
                );
            } else return (<div>Unable to authenticate!</div>)
        }
        return (
            <Grid container spacing={0} direction="column"
                alignItems="center" justify="center" style={{ minHeight: '75vh' }}>
                <CircularProgress />
            </Grid>
        );
    }
}

Secured.propTypes = {
    classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(Secured);
```

As you can see, to make `Dashboard` secured with KeyCloak, I put it inside the `Secured` component. Since `Public` and `Settings` are not inside `Secured`, they do not require authentication. That is fine with `Public`, however, I want `Settings` to be secured as well, i.e., users should be authenticated by KeyCloak first before they can see the page.

I have tried duplicating `Secured` and replacing `Dashboard` with `Settings` but I think it's kind of redundant. What if I have a dozen pages to secure? How do I efficiently do this?

Comment: create secured as a Higher order component. Wrap the component that you want to secure with this HOC.

you can also create a protected route to achieve this thing. It will prevent to render the route.

create a prviateRoute component which will return the component when authenticate else it will return some error based on scenarios.

Comment: Got it! I didn't know about protected routes. Googled it and found helpful resources. That term was all I needed. Thanks!